# API AJAX Toolkit, Possible to specify executions w/ and w/o sharing rules?

Tags: visualforce, sharing, ajax-toolkit

One can easily run the AJAX Toolkit, but it will always run respecting sharing rules.

Example of running a simple AJAX command would look as such: [Example Source](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm)

```
var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT c.Id, c.firstname, " +
    "c.lastname, c.leadsource, a.Id, a.name, a.industry, c.accountId " +
    "FROM Contact c, c.account a ORDER BY leadsource LIMIT 10");

  var it = new sforce.QueryResultIterator(result);

  while(it.hasNext()) {
    var record = it.next();
    var accountName = record.Account ? record.Account.Name : null;

    log( record.FirstName + " " + record.LastName +
         " in account " + accountName);
  }
```

*But what if I wanted to query all records not just the ones I had access to?*

*Or run DML statements which ignore sharing rules?*

Is there a way to set it up so it ignores sharing rules as you can do via apex classes with the attribute `without sharing`? I have not been able to find any documentation in regards to different types of permissions when making an execution call. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, no. The AJAX Toolkit runs in the same context as the SOAP API; it always honors the user's profile and field level security settings (making it even stricter than even Apex Code "with sharing").

If you want to query all records, see fields you can't normally access, or otherwise "break the rules", use JavaScript Remoting to call functions wrapped in "without sharing" classes in order to skirt sharing/security. Just be aware that if you can do it in code, users can reverse engineer to leverage in their browser's console.